# Waiting for last line from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

How can I store only the last line returned from a subprocess?

In particular, I call a subprocess from python and it returns a lot of output lines. The subprocess terminates after some unpredictable (and possibly very long) time and I need to process only  the last line from STDOUT.

Can I somehow avoid the storing of the whole output and just wait for the last one?

Comment: Can you just use `proc.stdout.readline()` in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to process (and discard) every line before reading the last one.

So you could do something like

```
line = None
for line in proc.stdout:
    pass
# now line is either the last line or None.
if line is not None:
    process(line)
```

Comment: So, there is no way to run the subprocess without reading all output lines? Just waiting for its finishing and then read the last line?
If not, I will go with this solution, it looks reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: @Czenek You could run two subprocesses and pipe the output of the interesting one into one running `tail -n 1`, but `tail` does the same thing you would do as well, so I don't see a benefit.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I just wanted to be sure if there is no better way to do it.